# Why my loop is repeat?

Tags: loop

Why my loop content is repeated 3 times?

Thank you

```
function tw_page_archive_content() {
    global $post;
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
    echo '<ul class="archives">';
        $lastposts = get_posts(
                array(
                    'numberposts' => -1, 
                    'offset' => 0, 
                    'category__in' => array($category),
                    'post_status'=>'publish',
                    'order'=>'ASC' 
                    )
                );
        $year = '';
        $month = '';
        foreach($lastposts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post);
            if(ucfirst(get_the_time('F')) != $month && $month != ''){
                echo '</ul></li>';
            }
            if(get_the_time('Y') != $year && $year != ''){
                echo '</ul></li>';
            }
            if(get_the_time('Y') != $year){
                $year = get_the_time('Y');
                echo '<li><h3>' . $year . '</h3><ul class="monthly-archives">';
            }
            if(ucfirst(get_the_time('F')) != $month){
                $month = ucfirst(get_the_time('F'));
                echo '<li><h2>' . $month . '</h2><ul>';
            }
        ?>
            <li>
                <span class="the_date"><?php the_time('d') ?>:</span>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?> 


        </ul>
```

Comment: where do you call this function?

Comment: In taxonomy.php for display my posts by category. It shows... but 4 times.

Comment: show your taxonomy.php code

Comment: Ok, now it is complete

Comment: Sounds like a question to ask at the Genesis support forum